# Numbered Bulleting workaround

Tags: ms-word

I have 2 different styles of bulleting (ie one is in neo sans and the other in times new roman) but I want to keep the numbering for these 2 ordered lists continuous. Is there some kind of hack or vba code to help me achieve this effect?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You need to do research and start this yourself.  We can help clean up a procedure that you write. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You may, instead, want to ask this on a more general Word forum, it is possible no vba is needed. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word

Comment: I see you did post in one of the Word forums and I will work with you there on it.